# Directions on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How can I get directions from one place to another on my Google Maps for Android at a specific time?

Surely by now it's learned how congested traffic is from 4:30 to 6:00.

Comment: Looks like you need to pay for this now. free for up to 2500 requests per day but a credit card is needed for overages. see traffic-model https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) departure_time, and only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID.

Comment: @Mapperz Please post your answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps requires a payment method even for a 'free service' (July 2018)
It is free up to 2500 requests per day but a credit card is needed for overages.

For more details see traffic-model

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model

Requirement:
The traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) departure_time, and only if the request includes an **API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID**